# Different threshold values in a matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have two matrices. In matrix1 are just the values 0 an 255. The other matrix has different values.

```
vec1 <- c(255,0,0,0,255,0,0,255,255,0)
vec2 <- c(0,255,0,255,0,0,255,255,0,0)
vec3 <- c(112,68,235,147,89,56,245,7,119,76)
vec4 <- c(194,158,13,41,182,218,5,78,195,235)

matrix1 <- matrix(c(vec1,vec2,vec1,vec2),10)
matrix2 <- matrix(c(vec3,vec4,vec3,vec4),10)
```

Now i want to define a threshold value for matrix2 so that there are also just
the values 0 and 255.

```
matrix2[matrix2 > 150] <- 255
matrix2[matrix2 <= 150] <- 0
```

And then i want to get the skill score from the two matrices.
These is for one threshold value but i want to have the skill scores
for all threshold values ( from 0 to 255).

```
a <- length(which(matrix1 == 255 & matrix2 == 255))
b <- length(which(matrix1 == 0 & matrix2 == 255))
c <- length(which(matrix1 == 255 & matrix2 == 0))
d <- length(which(matrix1 == 0 & matrix2 == 0))

KSS <- ((a*d)-(b*c))/((a+c)*(b+d))
```

I tried it with a for loop but it didn`t worked.

```
for (i in c(1:255)) {
  matrix2[matrix2 >i] <-255
  matrix2[matrix2 <= i] <-0
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is that you're changing the values of `matrix2` each time in the loop, So after the first loop all the values are 0 or 100 so different thresholds don't matter. How about something like this. First, we can define a `KSS` function that takes the two matrices, converts them to a 2x2 table and calculates the KSS value.

```
KSS <- function(a,b) {
    x <- table(factor(a, levels=c(0,100)), factor(b, levels=c(0,100)))
    ((x[2,2]*x[1,1])-(x[1,2]*x[2,1]))/((x[2,2]+x[2,1])*(x[1,2]+x[1,1]))
}
```

Then you can do

```
kss.val <- sapply(1:100, function(thresh) {
    KSS(matrix1, (matrix2 > thresh) * 100)
})
```

to get the KSS value for each threshold. Then you could plot the results if you like

```
plot(1:100, kss.val)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But i made a mistake..the matrix has values from 0 to 255

Answer (score 1):

For your threshold matrix, use the following construct:

```
(matrix2>50)*100
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    0  100    0  100
 [2,]  100  100  100  100
 [3,]    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0
 [5,]  100  100  100  100
 [6,]  100    0  100    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0  100    0  100
 [9,]    0  100    0  100
[10,]  100    0  100    0
```

For a,b,c and d you can simplify to (and not require the other threshold matrix at all):

```
a <- sum(!!matrix1 & !!(matrix2>50))
b <- sum(!matrix1 & !!(matrix2>50))
c <- sum(!!matrix1 & !(matrix2>50))
d <- sum(!matrix1 & !(matrix2>50))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but how can i do it when my values are going from 0 to 255?